# Rewrite URL string for username in root directory Apache

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, routes

Currently I have the following `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}% !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}% !-f
RewriteRule \.(js|css)$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^/?u/(.*?)/?$ /user-profile?user_id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

It rewrites all files and directories to `index.php`, which does further routing, ignoring static js/css files.

With this line:

```
RewriteRule ^/?u/(.*?)/?$ /user-profile?user_id=$1 [L]
```

I am redirecting all requests to something like `website.com/user-profile?user_id=timm` to `website.com/u/timm`. I'm trying to figure out how to make it redirect to simply `website.com/timm`, but everything I have tried so far has given me a 500 error.

Comment: _"with this line ... I am redirecting..."_ - no, you rewrite from left to right, not the other way round.

Comment: @smith if I remove that line, I can no longer use the static assets.

Comment: @Jeff Do you have a solution?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(timm)?$ /user-profile?user_id=$1 [L]` should do the trick (but I can't test it now)

Comment: @Jeff that does indeed work for the `timm` user, but I am searching for a solution that works for all users. So, whatever $1 is, I want to be the "subdirectory". I tried doing `^(1)?$`, `^($)?$`, `^(.+)?$`, `^(.*)?$`, etc.

Comment: Well, the left to right thing was good to know, because I can use `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /user-profile?user_id=$1 ` to set the correct controller, but $1 only equals index.php, so I'll need a new solution.

Comment: if you just want a rewrite rule to redirect `website.com/u/timm` to `website.com/timm`, try `RewriteRule ^\/u\/(\w+)$ /$1`

Comment: @Matt.G thank you, that helped me get in the right direction! I actually ended up doing `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?username-router=$1 [QSA,L]` and just routing user profiles based on if that get variable matched a user in the database. I have a list of unaccepted usernames, of course.

Comment: @anubhava Having website.com/username is a standard in web apps. The other way would have been fine, but this is what I wanted. And I'm routing all my URLs through index.php so it's not technically going to user-profile.php. It's actually going to index.php which is directing to the UserProfile controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I ended up going with, if anyone ever finds themselves in a similar situation. It might not match up to anyone else's use case, but you never know.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}%  !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}%  !-f
RewriteRule \.(js|css)$           -                            [L]
RewriteRule ^/?edit-list/(.*?)/?$ /edit-list?list_id=$1        [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$                index.php?username-router=$1 [QSA,L]
```

My entire router looks like this:

```
// Routing
$redirect = $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'];
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

// Get the path after the hostname
$path = ltrim($redirect, '/');

// Check if path matches a user
$username = $userControl->getUserByUsername(ltrim($path));

// Get controller name by converting URL of dashes
// (such as forgot-password) to uppercase class names
// (such as ForgotPassword) and assign to the proper
// controller based on URL.
$controllerName = getControllerName($redirect);
$controllerPath = $root . "/src/controllers/{$controllerName}.php";

// Load index page first
if ($controllerName === '') {
    $controller = new Index($session, $userControl);
}
// If the controller exists, route to the proper controlller 
elseif (file_exists($controllerPath)) { // to do: add approved filenames
    $controller = new $controllerName($session, $userControl);
}
// If path matches user in the database, route to the public
// user profile.
elseif ($username) {
    $controller = new UserProfile($session, $userControl);
} 
// If all else fails, 404.
else {
    $controller = new ExceptionNotFound($session, $userControl);
}

// Detect if method is GET or POST and route accordingly.
if ($method === 'POST') {
    $controller->post();
} else {
    $controller->get();
}
```